# Removing dash string from mixed dtype column in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, types, numeric

I have a dataframe with possible objects mixed with numerical values.

My target is to change every value to a simple integer, however, some of these values have `-` between numbers.

A minimal working example looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'API':[float(4433), float(3344), 6666, '6-9-11', '8-0-11', 9990]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I try:

```
df['API'] = df['API'].str.replace('-','')
```

But this leaves me with `nan` for the numeric types because it's searching the entire frame for the strings only.

The output is:

```
API

nan
nan
nan
6911
8011
nan
```

I'd like an output:

```
API

4433
3344
6666
6911
8011
9990
```

Where all types are `int`.

Is there an easy way to take care of just the object types in the Series but leaving the actual numericals in tact? I'm using this technique on large data sets (300,000+ lines) so something like `lambda` or `series operations` would be preferred over a loop search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`df.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`

```
df = df.replace('-', '', regex=True).astype(int)

    API
0   4433
1   3344
2   6666
3   6911
4   8011
5   9990
```

Comment: Simple fix!

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

Also,

```
df['API'] = df['API'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('-', '')).astype(int)
```

Comment: try: `df.API=df.API.str.replace('-','').fillna(df.API)`